# recursion apparently has non exhaustive patterns in it

Tags: haskell

My function rtnDryPlaces is supposed to return a list of all dry places if they were dry on a particular day - with day 1 being yesterday (last element) and day 7 being last week (first element).

```
type Name = String
type Location = (Float,Float)
type RainfallFigures = [Int]
type Place = (Name,Location,RainfallFigures)

testData=[("London", (51.5, -0.1), [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0]),("Cardiff", (51.5 , -3.2),[12, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, 2])]
rtnDryPlaces :: [Place] -> Int -> [Name]
rtnDryPlaces ((a,(b,c),d):xs) n
 | d == [] = []
 | (reverse d)!!n-1 == 0 = a:rtnDryPlaces xs n

demo 4 = print (rtnDryPlaces testData 2 )
```

The second guard reverses the list and returns the element at that index (index is day). If it returns 0, then the name a is appended to the list of names which have also returned 0 for that day. When the test data runs out, so does the rainfall data so I've set the stop condition to be when d = []

Comment: `rtnDryPlaces []` was not defined. Only `rtnDryPlaces ((a,(b,c),[]):_)` was defined. Turning on warnings would report this.

Comment: how do I define it?

Comment: You just write `rtnDryPlaces [] _ = <something>`

Comment: It keeps giving me a parse error when I write the statement above the guards, and a 'No instance for (Num [Name]) arising from the literal ‘0’' error when I write it below

Comment: @jamie What exactly did you write above/below? I guess you wrote `rtnDryPlaces [] _ = 0`, but `0` is an instance of `Num` while what we actually expect to return is something of type `[Name]`, I guess you could replac the `0` with `[]`.

Comment: It’s still giving me a non exhaustive patterns error

Comment: @jamie it's pretty much impossible to guess what exactly you wrote and what the error may be. If you expect to receive help, please be as clear as possible. For example, include the new code in the question, or perhaps ask a new question with the new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems is that the recursive calls will eventually reach the empty list, and you did not define a result for that:

```
rtnDryPlaces :: [Place] -> Int -> [Name]
rtnDryPlaces [] _ = []
rtnDryPlaces ((a,(b,c),d):xs) n
    | d == [] = []
    | (reverse d)!!n-1 == 0 = a:rtnDryPlaces xs n
```

But even then it will not work (yet). For example `(reversed d)!!n-1` is interpreted as `((reverse d)!!n)-1`, so it first takes the element at index `n`, and then it will subtract that element with `1`. It will *not* take the *n-1* element.

Furthermore if the `(reversed d)!!(n-1)` is not zero, then that guard will not "*fire*", and thus we get again an exhaustive pattern failure. We thus should add an `otherwise` at the end:

```
rtnDryPlaces :: [Place] -> Int -> [Name]
rtnDryPlaces [] _ = []
rtnDryPlaces ((a,_,d):xs) n
    | d == [] = []
    | (reverse d)!!(n-1) == 0 = a:rtnDryPlaces xs n
    | otherwise = rtnDryPlaces xs n
```

Now this will give us a result:

```
Prelude> rtnDryPlaces testData 2
["London","Cardiff"]
```

But we can still make this more elegant by making use of `filter` and `map`:

```
rtnDryPlaces :: [Place] -> Int -> [Name]
rtnDryPlaces ps n = map (\(x,_,_) -> x) (filter p ps)
    where p (_,_,d) | (0:_) <- drop (n-1) (reverse d) = True
                    | otherwise = False
```

or as [@DanielWagner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61324617/recursion-apparently-has-non-exhaustive-patterns-in-it/61326147?noredirect=1#comment108491102_61326147), with list comprehension:

```
rtnDryPlaces :: [Place] -> Int -> [Name]
rtnDryPlaces ps n = [p | (p, _, d) <- ps, 0 <- take 1 . drop (n-1) . reverse $ d]
```

Here the `take 1 . drop (n-1)` will make a singleton list (given the list has enough elements) with the amount of rain for that day. If that then pattern matches with `0`, we will yield `p` in the result. If the value for that day does not match with `0`, or the list has not enough elements (then `take 1 . drop (n-1) (reverse d)` will yield an empty list), then that element is not emitted in the result.

Comment: Or a list comprehension: `[x | (x, _, d) <- ps, 0 <- take 1 . drop (n-1) . reverse $ d]`